# Trying to write strcpy in assembly at&t, no output

Tags: string, loops, pointers, assembly, att

I am trying to write the `char *my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *source);` in assembly, at&t syntax, that should act exactly like strcpy from C. My c file looks like this:

Comment: I don't use AT&T syntax myself, but I am pretty sure this `mov %rsi, %rdi` just copies the pointer in `rsi` to `rdi`. To move the byte you'll need to do something like `mov (%rsi), %al; mov %al, (%rdi)`.

Comment: I tried to do movb %rsi, %rdi but it says too many arguments..

Comment: You mean it segfaults before it returns?  You should say that, not just "outputs nothing"!

Comment: Note that `strcpy` is supposed to return `char *`, not `size_t`, and the return value should simply equal `dest`.  That's what your code actually does, but maybe not what you thought it did.

Comment: I want to return a pointer to dest. Where did I introduce size_t ?

Comment: @catrev: `extern size_t my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *source);`

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions.  I rolled back the edit that removed most of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.globl my_strcpy

my_strcpy:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    mov %rdi, %rax
    jmp copy_loop
```

The jump is pointless.

```
copy_loop:
    cmp $0, (%rsi)
```

You didn't specify whether this should be an 8, 16, 32 or 64-bit compare.  When I assemble it, I get a 32-bit compare; e.g. it sees whether the 32-bit word at address `%rsi` equals zero.  You need to change this to `cmpb $0, (%rsi)`.

```
    je end
    mov %rsi, %rdi
```

As user 500 noted, this copies the address in the `%rsi` register into the `%rdi` register, overwriting it.  This is not what you want.  You probably intended something like `movb (%rsi), (%rdi)`, but no such instruction actually exists: x86 does not have such a single instruction to move memory to memory (special exception: see the `movsb` instruction).  So you'll need to first copy the byte at address `%rsi` into a register, and then copy it onward with another instruction, e.g.  `mov (%rsi), %cl ; mov %cl, (%rdi)`.  Note the use of the 8-bit `%cl` register makes it unambiguous that these should be one-byte moves.

`movzbl (%rsi), %ecx` is a more efficient way to load a byte on modern x86.  You still store it by reading CL with `mov %cl, (%rdi)`, but overwriting the whole RCX instead of merging into RCX is better.

```
    addq $1, %rsi
    addq $1, %rdi
```

You might like to learn about the `inc` instruction, but `add` is fine.

```
    je copy_loop
```

I think you mean `jmp copy_loop`, since the jump here should happen unconditionally.  (Or you should rearrange your loop so the conditional branch can be at the bottom.  Since you want to copy the terminating `0` byte, you can just copy and *then* check for 0, like `do{}while(c != 0)`)

```
end:
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks I have understood my mistakes, but is there another way to move 1 byte at a time other than saving it into the %al register ?

Comment: @catrev: yes, as this answer already shows, you can load it into `%cl` or any other 8-bit register you want!  Or use `movsb` like this answer also mentions, but that's slowish.  (If you care about performance, you'd use SSE2 to copy 16 bytes at a time, though, after finding an alignment boundary.)

Comment: So I can use ANY register ?

Comment: @catrev: Well, you're already using `%rax` to store the return value, so unless you change that, you can't use `%al` or `%ah`.  And `%rbx` is a callee-saved register, so you can't use `%bl` or `%bh` unless you want to save and restore `%rbx`.  That's why I chose `%cl`.

Comment: @catrev: obviously not `sil` or `dil` because then you'd destroy the pointer values.  But yes, any call-clobbered register would be equally good.  Also, see my update to this answer; you forgot to copy the terminating `0` byte because you're leaving the loop before storing it.

Comment: But when I return, %rax sends what ? which address ?

Comment: @catrev: As your code currently stands, you copy `%rdi` into `%rax` and never change `%rax` after that, so when you return, that's what it still contains. So you end up returning the initial value from `%rdi`, i.e. the `dest` pointer, which is what you want.

Comment: And is the address of my source buffer %rsi changed ? Because it is not supposed to change since it is a const char

Comment: @catrev: The address of the buffer didn't change.  The contents of `%rsi` change over the course of the function, so that it no longer points to the start of the source buffer but somewhere inside it.  But nobody cares what `%rsi` contains when your function exits.

Comment: Keep in mind that `const char *src` doesn't mean that the pointer itself is a constant; it means that the memory which it points to is constant and should not be modified.

Comment: I do care since I want to use that later, how would we make %rsi point at the same address ?

Comment: You want to use it later in `my_strcpy`, or later in `main`?  If in `my_strcpy`, I don't understand what you would do with it, but if you want the original value of `src` later in the function, you'll have to save it in another register before you modify `%rsi`.  If you mean later in `main`, then it doesn't matter; the code for `main` already knows the address of `str1` somewhere else, and just copies that address into `%rsi`.  Remember C passes arguments by value!  So `my_strcpy` can modify `%rsi` however it wants, and it will have no effect on the variables in `main`.